# Using gparted, what do I need to do to make a new partition that will have all of the unused space available to that 3rd partition?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

**PURPOSE**: **Determine how to use all of the space "left" on the ext hdd for a 3rd partition, not including the 7.5% lost out-of-the-box.**

The hdd is 2TB with "originally" 1.84TB free for use. I made 2 partitions, one used 0.50TB and the other one used 0.90TB.

There should be over 400GB left of free space.

But the hdd is saying that there is only 128MB of space left for the 3rd partition.

When I made the 2nd partition, I did NOT have to 'resize' the 1st partition. I set the size to the full amount of GB left on the hdd, which is the way the hdd came with one partition (all GB on 1st partition, apparently).

There is a triangular icon sitting on one of the partitions in gparted. I have seen it there before I made the 2nd partition, but it goes away and then comes back - I have no idea how or why.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your GParted window, and/or `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` (sdb, sdc...)

Comment: You are apparently confused with unused space of a partition/filesystem and unused (i.e. unpartitioned) space of a disk...

Comment: @TomYan Thanks. Yes, I see the unallocated MB for the partition filesystem. I know that is not what i want to use, but when I tried to make a new partition, I couldn't seem to create a new partition.

Comment: at grawity: I was in the process of copying the screen and decided to resize the partition, thereby freeing up the unused space. It's shrinking it right now. I'll update. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to shrink the 2nd partition and create a 3rd one, so I think all is well. I think the "triangle" signified something to do with flagging that there was extra space there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: 2 TB, or 2'000'000'000'000 bytes, is actually ~1.82 [TiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix). Most "2 TB" HDDs are slightly larger, e.g. these Seagate HDDs I recently bought are ~2.0004 TB (or exactly 2000398934016 bytes), and this makes just around 1.84 TiB in binary units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using gparted, shrink the 2nd partition, create a 3rd partition by clicking on 'new' in the dropdown menu under 'partition', while highlighting the hdd newly created unallocated space - not the filesystem unallocated space.